# How to make the effect of gradually appearing video in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Good afternoon.
Can you please tell me how to make slow video appear
So that the video appears gradually from top to bottom or bottom to top? And from right to left.
Thank you!
https://youtube.com/shorts/EzhuvJg8WsQ?feature=share

Why doesn't the script work?

```
@Echo Off
cd input1
dir /b *.mp4 > ..\temp.txt
cd ..
(FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (temp.txt) DO (
xffmpeg\FFmpeg-x86_64-N-74566-g531b0a3\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "input1\%%G" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -an ^
-filter_complex "crop=in_w:in_h/2:0:0, drawbox=x=0:y=h/2-w/2:w=in_w:h=in_h/2:t=30:color=black, crop=in_w:in_h/2:0:h/2, curtain=vertical:0.4:0.2:0.05, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -c:a copy -vf hflip "output\%%~nG_1.mp4"
))
```

Comment: blend http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#blend-1 Apply uncover down effect example